# How to create a new column that gets count by groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset with Employee history. Including Name, ID number, Job, Manager, Manager ID, and Termed(1 = Termed or 0 = Active). Here is a sample.

df =

```
Name        Emp_ID      Job        Manager      Manager_ID      Termed 
Adam         100       Sales       Steve           103            0
Beth         101       Sales       Steve           103            0 
Rick         102       Tech        John            106            0 
Steve        103       Sales Mgr.  Lisa            110            0
Drake        104       Tech        John            106            1
Sarah        105       Sales       Steve           103            1
John         106       Tech Mgr.   Rodger          122            0
Mike         107       Sales       Steve           103            1
```

I would like to findout by manager how many `1` or Terminated employees each manager has.
The code I tried was `df['term_count'] = df.groupby('Manager_ID')['Termed'].sum()`
When I try this code I get a **NaN** value when I'm not sure why. This is the desired output.

df =

```
Name     Emp_ID     Job       Manager     Manager_ID       Termed      term_count
Adam      100      Sales       Steve        103               0             0
Beth      101      Sales       Steve        103               0             0
Rick      102      Tech        John         106               0             0 
Steve     103      Sales Mgr.  Lisa         110               0             2
Drake     104      Tech        John         106               1             0
Sarah     105      Sales       Steve        103               1             0 
John      106      Tech Mgr.   Rodger       122               0             1
Mike      107      Sales       Steve        103               1             0
```

Any suggestions would be great thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use additional `pd.Series.map` on aggregated sums:

```
df['term_count'] = df['Emp_ID'].map(df.groupby('Manager_ID')['Termed'].sum()).fillna(0)
```

---

```
    Name  Emp_ID         Job Manager  Manager_ID  Termed  term_count
0   Adam     100       Sales   Steve         103       0         0.0
1   Beth     101       Sales   Steve         103       0         0.0
2   Rick     102        Tech    John         106       0         0.0
3  Steve     103  Sales Mgr.    Lisa         110       0         2.0
4  Drake     104        Tech    John         106       1         0.0
5  Sarah     105       Sales   Steve         103       1         0.0
6   John     106   Tech Mgr.  Rodger         122       0         1.0
7   Mike     107       Sales   Steve         103       1         0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge with the groupby results:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('Manager_ID')['Termed'].sum().reset_index(), left_on='Emp_ID', right_on = 'Manager_ID', how='left').fillna(0)
df.rename(columns={'Termed_x': 'Termed', 'Termed_y': 'term_count'}, inplace=True)
df
```